# texlive incompatible version

Tags: installing, versions

I am trying to install TexLive 2019 by:

1. Download install-tl-unx.tar.gz from http://tug.org/texlive/pkginstall.html
2. `gunzip install-tl-unx.tar.gz`
3. `tar -xf install*`
4. `./install-tl --no-verify-downloads`

but keep getting the message:

```
 ./install-tl: The TeX Live versions of the local installation
and the repository being accessed are not compatible:
      local: 2019
 repository: 2021
Perhaps you need to use a different CTAN mirror?
```

How do I install an older TexLive version?

Comment: if you install an old version you will not have any access to live updates, you would need to grab an image of a complete distribution. the infrastuctucture for installing from the internet and tlmgr updates is only maintained for the current year's release

Comment: at the site you mention there is only texlive 2021

Comment: When you unpack that `tar.gz` file it creates a folder. What is the name of that folder? It can tell us which version you are using. Additionally `./install-tl` will list which repository it is installing from. Please provide this information as well.

Comment: When I downloaded install-tl-unx.tar.gz from http://tug.org/texlive/pkginstall.html (in 2019) and unpacked it I got a folder with name install-tl-20191231.

Comment: you are using an old 2019 installer from somewhere not the one currently on the texlive site,you shouldn't need to call both tar and zip: follow the steps at https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html unzip the package cd into the directory then run the  script

Comment: that net installer will no longer work, you need to get the 2021 version

Comment: As David says, never use an old installer. Always go to https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html and download a new `tar.gz` every time. It is continuouslty being updated.